# Calculating the Font-size of textinput using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on an MVC framework for javascript, where the content is rendering from XML.
I am stucked in a problem.I need to find the font-size of textinput that is generating dynamically from xml. Based upon the font-size of text input I have to do some calculation.

Is there a way to calculate the font-size of text coming inside the textinput.

I can use Jquery/javascript for this purpose.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Javascript:

```
var size = document.getElementById("inputId").style.fontSize;
```

> **Note**: You can only get font size if it is set using inline css

Better solution is **Jquery**

```
var size = $('#inputId').css("font-size");
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0h827Lz6/3/)

Comment: That's only going to work if the font size is set using inline CSS in the first place

Comment: @Quentin you are correct so i have added jquery solution also

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery:

```
var fontsize = $('#yourtextinputid').css("font-size");// Returns a string such as "19px".
```

Please note that this will append "px" along with the size.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't a pure Javascipt solution try this:

```
var input = document.getElementById('some-input-field');
var fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(input, null).getPropertyValue("font-size");
```

- [Browsersupport](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getcomputedstyle)
- **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7tygeemr/)**